# Laravel homestead directory is refusing to sync

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I am having some trouble getting vagrant/homestead virtual machine to sync up with my real machine.

I am following the laravel homestead guide here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead

I think the problem is due to my virtual machine having the directory "Code" and my real machine having the directory "code" (notice the uppercase 'C').

Here is the directories on my virtual machine...

[image]

and my yaml file directories

[image]

To be honest this is all very overwhelming and the tutorial is so unclear to me as a n00b.

So my question is simple, how to I change the upper-case Code directory on my virtual machine to a lower-case 'code'.

Many thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Here are the steps I am going through...

1: Update my Homestead.yaml as follows

[image]

2: I open that command prompt in the ~/Homestead directory and type in the following and nothing has changed!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You map the directories within the Homestead.yaml, under `folders`

```
folders:
    - map: /Directory/to/your/pc/folder
      to: /home/vagrant/code
```

Comment: So in my case it would look like    map: C:\Users\Jethro\code?

Comment: or /Users/Jethro/code? I will try both now... thanks for your quick response!

Comment: So I have tried both options and it is not working, I have updated my answer with the steps I go throught,

Comment: Your init.sh is overwriting Homestead.yaml, so you may need to update it there instead.

Comment: Sorry it's not clear to me, update it where? Could you be a little more explicit?

Comment: Do I need to update something on the virtual machine?

Comment: It depends on where init.sh is. The first command you run is `bash init.sh`. That file overwrites your Homestead.yaml. You'll have to look inside of `init.sh` to find out what it's writing into Homestead.yaml.